# What is the 90 days chat thread and message data storing about in Azure Communication Service?

Tags: azure, azure-policy, azure-communication-services

I am a beginner with Azure Communication Service and came across this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/concepts/privacy#chat) about chat threads and messages being deleted after 90 days due to internal policies.
I am not sure if this refers to data retention policy. I find it not documented well and can't find any further information.

What I want to know for sure:
Are my created chat threads and messages just gone forever after those 90 days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you are working on a POC communication application with Azure communication Services (ACS), and want to retain chats and messages for 7 years. Thanks for your interest in ACS for your solution!

To benefit the community with an update here. My colleague, Grmacjon-MSFT is working with you offline on your [Microsoft Q&A thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1188359/is-it-possible-to-store-chat-threads-and-message-d), we are also discussing on this internally with our ACS product engineering team.